# Why can't I mount an f2fs partition on a HDD?

Tags: mount, hard-drive, f2fs

I want to mount a partition of a (large) HDD with an F2FS file system on it.
I created a (large) primary partition on the HDD using parted, then created a file system on the partition using `mkfs.f2fs`.  Supposedly, all went well.
But when I tried to mount the partition using `mount`, I got an error:

```
$ mount -t f2fs /dev/sdb1 /mount
mount: /dev/sdb1 can't read superblock
```

So, I ran

```
fsck -t f2fs /dev/sdb1
```

and was told that the file system is fine.  But according to `dmesg | tail`, the file system failed to read the root inode.  What's the deal here?

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04.1, Linux kernel `3.13.0-46-generic` on an x86_64 system.  Thanks for any help!!

Comment: Oops!  I was wrong about `fsck` saying the file system is fine.  In fact, `fsck` notes a CRC error (somewhere--presumably in the superblock) but apparently does not fix it.  It seems that `mkfs.f2fs` always creates the file system with the CRC error.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that f2fs doesn't properly support large partitions.  I was able to create and mount an F2FS file system on a partition of 2 TBytes, but not a partition of 4 TBytes, even though `mkfs.f2fs` did not complain about the large partition size.

Answer (score 1):

The bug-fix patch to support large volume over 2TB were merged on 1.4.0 in f2fs-tools and Kernel v3.16.

Can you try them?